# Windows Azure ends connection and returns a 324 error code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I have tried some labs in Windows Azure and it works fine. So, I start developing my application with Azure Emulator.

I perform my first deployment test today in Windows Azure and have a first issue:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10000

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10000

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SocketException (0x274d): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:10000]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +2724507
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +392

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() +96
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait() +271
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobContainer.Delete(BlobRequestOptions options) +213
   MyProject.Web.MvcApplication.InitBlobs() in C:\Sites\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.Web\Global.asax.cs:85
   MyProject.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in C:\Sites\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject.Web\Global.asax.cs:52
```

It was the first deployment, so I tried to delete a container that doesn't exist.
I now handle the Exception.

I redeploy my project and doesn't get any server error. It just ends the connection and leave me this error: `Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)`

I assume I miss something in my configuration but I wasn't able to find what it is exactly.

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
The deployment itself is the first one for this application, but it isn't the first one I perform on Windows Azure. I already deployed some msdn labs when I start developing for Windows Azure.

Comment: I noticed from the stack trace that it looks like you're calling to Blob storage from global.asax.cs - could you try doing this from a controller action instead and see if you get the same error?  Also, I saw the message "unable to connect to remote server".  are you sure the account name and account key are accurate and both from the same storage account?  i've messed that up before and gotten weird errors...

Comment: I try to move the call of blob storage in my `HomeController` but it doesn't change anything. I already have checked my credentials. They are all valid an associated with the same account. I also tried to put my connexion string directly in the `global.asax` method instead of calling a key of the `configuration manager` but it doesn't work. Something I cannot understand is why the app try to connect to `127.0.0.1:10000` while I am using Windows Azure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what my mistake was.

In my desire of abstraction, I designed a solution where I used the blob connection only a very few time in my app. There was 3 call to the blob storage.

- One in my `Global.asax`
- One in a `BlobService`
- One in an `ExtensionMethod`

I checked several times my Global.asax and BlobService but forgot the ExtensionMethod. I wrote it in the beginning of my project and I was accessing my blob account only in development by the following instruction: `CloudStorageAccount.DevelopmentStorageAccount` instead of `CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("BlobConnection"))`

Chris Koening [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955560/windows-azure-ends-connection-and-returns-a-324-error-code/11973439#11973439) was partially right, because I was trying to access development storage whereas I was in the Cloud. If you have the same problem describe in this question, my advise would be:

1. Execute Chris answer
2. If it doesn't solve your issue, try to find the `DevelopmentStorageAccount` string in your entire solution via Visual Studio search tool or [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?page=download&type=agentransack%20Agent%20Ransack) and replace it with the key you defined in first step
3. If it still doesn't solve your issue, try to find if there is any reference to the DevelopmentStorage anywhere else

Comment: I got the same error when I try to run on localhost using Azure Storage Emulator. It happens on call "container.CreateIfNotExists()". After much struggle, it turns out, in my case, the emulator wasn't started. Right click the Azure taskbar icon and click Start Storage Emulator. Once started, it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

OK - I was able to reproduce this, and the problem is with the configuration of your cloud deployment project.

[image: My version of the error]

The reason I got this error is because I set the storage connection string to point to `"UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"`. Instead you need to use the Connection String tool in your Azure Deployment Project to change where the `ConfigurationManager` gets its connection string and have one for Local development and a different one for deploying to the Cloud:

- Open your Windows Azure Project and find the **Roles** node.
- Double-click on your WebRole project to open the configuration panel
- Click on the **Settings** tab to show all the different settings defined for your project.  You will probably see something like this:

[image: Configuration Panel]

- Notice the `Service Configuration` combo box at the top.  My settings, as displayed in the picture, currently indicate that the `StorageConnectionString` setting will be applied to **both** the Cloud and the Local deployments.  That's bad.
- See the one beneath it? The second one?  That one shows `<Select Configuration>` in the Value column as the value will be dependent on which configuration you're running.

To fix this, it's a matter of changing the Service Configuration to `Cloud` and then adjusting the settings:

- Change the `Service Configuration` setting to **Cloud**
- Click on the elipses at the end of the `StorageConnectionString` setting and choose **Enter storage credentials**.

[image: Configuration Settings]

- Save this dialog, and the configuration settings page, and go back into your code where you create the `CloudStorageAccount` client.
- In the place that you need to get the connection string to create the client, use the following snippet:

  // Retrieve storage account from connection-string
  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));
- The `storageAccount` is now loaded from the correct connection string based on whether you're publishing to Cloud or Local.

When the deployment wizard runs, it will pull in the **Cloud** settings automatically, while preserving the **Local** settings for running in the debugger.

Try this out and let me know if it doesn't work for you. I'd be happy to join a Lync meeting to walk through your code and get this fixed up if you're open to that...

Comment: I already defined my storage credentials in different configurations (I have three configuration, one for local development, one for testing, and one for production. testing and production are to distinct Windows Azure account). I suspected there was an attempt of connecting to localhost, so I try to hard-code my testing credential directly in my application an run it in windows azure but I still have the same issue.

Comment: I was accessing my setting by the RoleEnvironment instead of CloudConfigurationManager like so: `CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("BlobConnection"));`. I don't really hope this will change anything but I am already trying your method to call the setting. I am deploying my project on Azure and let you know if there is any change.

Comment: The new deployment I tested still doesn't change anything. I also tried to put my testing credentials in my local connection string instead of UseDevelopmentStorage=true. It compute, but the blob I saved in the container (supposed to be in my testing account blob) is stored in the storage emulator. I check in debug mode, the pulled string from cloud settings is my testing connection string. So, I don't understand why there isn't any error raised, and why I is saving my blob in another location that I want.

Comment: I think this is at a point where I'd have to see the code to be able to diagnose any further.  The tutorials on how to do this are pretty straight-forward, but something must have gone crooked somwhere along the line of customization.  Any chance you could repro with a simple code sample, or share what you've written?  You can email me directly at chris.koenig@microsoft.com if that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is specific to the component installed on your machine, rather then Windows Azure Specific. I can provide a few pointers to troubleshoot such problem however it would be very hard to pinpoint one specific root cause.

What you can do it just create a very simple Web Role application directly from template and then run it in Windows Azure Emulator to see if that works fine or not. This way you can distinguish if your problem is specific to your code or not. If you hit the exact same problem with a simple test app, then your problem is more of Windows Azure components related.

You can also modify your Application setting to run either on IISExpress (default) or IIS Server to see there is change in problem behavior. If you get exact same error with both IIS Server and IIS Express, then you can focus on your Windows Azure components to troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, I already deployed some lab from msdn and it worked perfectly fine.